# Create unblocked user in Joomla using PHP

Tags: php, joomla

Despite setting "block" to 0 I cannot create a user who is unblocked. I am able to successfully create users, but I cannot have them be set up from the beginning as unblocked.

```
$data = array(
"name"=>$name,
"username"=>$username,
"password"=>$password,
"password2"=>$password,
"email"=>$email,
"block"=>0,
"sendEmail"=>0,
"groups"=>$arrGroups
);
```

If you are wondering why I would ever do this it's because I am confident that users who get this far are not bots.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you doing this in a CLI? Or a component? Plugin? You are creating a user. Why don't you use that API to unblock? You need to show the code you are using to create the user, but in general users cannot unblock themselves. You might want to change the global configuration so that users are not defaulted to blocked.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely the code for creating unblocked users. `$data['block']` should be 0. Are you sure that the user was actually blocked and not something else? Have you checked the row created in the database and checked that the `block` field is set to 1?

Are you 100% sure that the above piece of code is the one being executed when the users are created blocked?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm pretty sure that it is the code being executed, but I will have to investigate it further.
But yeah, the user does seem to actually be blocked.

Comment: No that is definitely not the code for creating an unblocked user.  You need to check what the default value is for this on configuration.php because that is the value that is going to set. There is an api to deal with unblocking once the user has been saved ... also note that there is a `$block` property of the user object.